# How do I fix "NameError: Name 'date' is not defined"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some errors when I try and plot some data:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pylab 
pylab.show()
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")

def graphRawFX(): date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('XAUUSDS.txt', unpack=True,
delimiter='\t'  ,
converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%d%m%Y%H%M%S%F')})
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)
ax1.plot(date,bid)
ax1.plot(date,ask)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S:%F.'))

for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels(): label.set_rotation(45)
plt.subplotls_adjust(bottom=.23)
plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().setuseoffset(False)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
graphRawFX()
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

The error I get is:

> NameError: Name 'date' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pylab 
pylab.show()
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")

def graphRawFX(): 
    date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('XAUUSDS.txt', 
                              unpack=True, 
                              delimiter='\t'  ,
                              converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%d%m%Y%H%M%S%F')})
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)
    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S:%F.'))

    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels(): 
        label.set_rotation(45)
    plt.subplotls_adjust(bottom=.23)
    plt.gca().get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().setuseoffset(False)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
    graphRawFX()
    plt.savefig('foo.png')

if __name__=='__main__':
    graphRawFX()
```

You should use indentation to define the scope of function.

Comment: im using note pad++ , if i run it on python shell it seems to work but then i get errors in the dates

Comment: @LibertySIlver You got indentation error or NameError after using my suggested code?

Comment: no it worked thank you , i got a Value error: time data ' ' dose not match for mat , my date layout is like this 08.05.2015 04:00:00.648

Answer (score 0):

`date` only exists inside the `graphRawFX` function (also `bid` and `ask`). Use a global object, or better return it from your function to use it in an outer scope.